# How can I get the inventory level of an item from Amazon using MWS API?

Tags: amazon-mws

For those who are Amazon ninja, I am wondering if there is the API to retrieve the number of stocks available for the items that are listed in Amazon? I know that Amazon provides that service for those who have registered for Amazon's FBA (Fulfillment by Amazon), but that's not what I'm looking for. I would like to get the inventory levels of the products using non-FBA Amazon APIs. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_ report for non-FBA products and _GET_AFN_INVENTORY_DATA_ report for FBA product's Inventory

Answer (score -2):

I am sorry but you can not access this information with out access to MWS api services.

Comment: The question is asking how to get it with MWS. Obviously there is already access in that scenario.